# "Might as well been" vs "could have been"

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrase-usage

Are both of them interchangeable when used as a simile? Example:

> Her embrace was so subtle, so silent he **could have been** touched by a
>   gentle breeze.
>
> Her embrace was so subtle, so silent he **might as well been** touched by a
>   gentle breeze.

(I wanted to check this theory on Google but I don't know what to search for.)

Answer (score 2):

The phrases are not equivalent.

*Could be/could have been* and *mould be/might have been* may both be used as you intend, to introduce a simile, more or less equivalent to "It was as if he were/had been".

*Might as well **been*** is ungrammatical: *might* requires an infinitival complement. Present-tense *might as well VERB* and past-tense *might as well have VERBen* are always used to express a  comparison to something relatively undesirable or ineffective, "Things would be no better if SUBJECT VERBed/had VERBen":

> I might as well go home, I'm not accomplishing anything here.
>   He's not going to listen, she might as well save her breath.
>   I might as well be dead for all the attention he pays to my ideas.